# m2eclipse: Multi-module and parent build exception

Tags: maven, maven-2, build, dependencies, m2eclipse

I am new to m2eclipse, and I created a dummy java project (mytest4) and checked `enable dependency management`, after that, the plugin created a pom.xml file. I manually added `parent` information, such as `groupId`, `artifactId` and `version`, etc. to the dummy project. Then I added modules to the parent project, and the parent `projectType` is `pom` not `jar`. However, when I build using `clean install`, I get an error:

```
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.multimod:myproject:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> 
    [Help 1]org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
    [ERROR] Child module C:\workspace\myproject\mytest4 of C:\workspace\myproject\pom.xml does not exist @ 

[ERROR] The project com.multimod:myproject:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT(C:\workspace\myproject\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR] Child module C:\workspace\myproject\mytest4 of C:\workspace\myproject\pom.xml does not exist
```

I don't understand `C:\workspance\myproject\pom.xml` does not exist.

Could you give some hints?
Thank you.

Comment: Please make sure that your error message is readable and is not just a single long line

Comment: My problem is convert maven module project from existing java project in eclipse? Any idea how to convert from existing java project to maven module project using m2eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to set the relative path to you parent pom file in the mytest4 pom file. The default is `../pom.xml` hence your path `C:\workspace\myproject\pom.xml`.

As to your sub question in the comment. Right click on the project en select `Configure > Convert to Maven Project`